# Chrome freeze due to JS in some video boxes when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, video, hover, freeze

This is a chrome browser freeze due to JS in some video boxes when hovering. very annoying and disruptive to visitors.
Days ago using the inspector, something similar to this appeared:

**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted**

Any help to solve this problem would be welcome :)
Thanks, have a nice day

URL:
https://www.valezart.com/audiovisual/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".myvideo").on("mouseover", function(event) {
$(this).get(0).play();
}).on('mouseout', function(event) {
this.load();
});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<a href="https://www.valezart.com/audiovisual/dreamsoul">
<div class="video-box">
<video class="myvideo" width="100%" height="auto" alt=""
poster="https://www.valezart.com/videoplayer/poster-dreamsoul.webp"
muted loop>
<source
src="https://www.valezart.com/videoplayer/dreamsoul_preview.mp4"
type='video/mp4'></video>
</div>
</a>
```

### **FUNCTIONALITY, WHAT IS EXPECTED?**

When the user hovers on any of the boxes, a short video of about 10-15s is played in a loop. Upon exiting the boxes (unhover), stops and displays the video poster.

### **THE PROBLEMO**

The code works but it has a bug or a malfunction. Randomly passing the mouse over the
boxes (hover) it's possible that the browser (specifically Chrome) will freeze. Sometimes it takes time but it ends up happening. Try incognito mode. Both Chrome and the boxes are frozen and if you try to refresh the page, it doesn't respond until after a few minutes. This is a problem as any visitor will close the window as they cannot navigate after this event.

Comment: Full error message is `The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.`  Makes sense, since you are quickly calling play and load when you hover over/out of the box.

Comment: Explanation and some potential workarounds [here](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/421)